# Use macros in numerica vv-list

Tags: expansion

I want to use macros in the variable=value list of the `\nmcEvaluate` command of the package "numerica". However the command parses the list by tokens without expanding. I can not expand the whole list beforehand because math commands must not be expanded. Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numerica}
\begin{document}
     \nmcEvaluate{\[\sin\alpha\]}[\alpha=0.35]
     
     \def\myvalue{0.35}
     \nmcEvaluate{\[\sin\alpha\]}[\alpha=\myvalue]
\end{document}
```

[image: latex output]

Comment: Welcome! It's a pity that the doc for `numerica` uses the `minimal` class for its examples; don't do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a slightly cumbersome way. Maybe a feature request is in order.

The package will read a file called `\jobname.nmc` if the `\nmcReuse` command is used (in the preamble) (`\jobname` stands for the name of the main TeX file). You can make the thing self-contained by using `filecontents`. Any number of constants can be put in the file. Using the `overwrite` option will guarantee that the file is rewritten at each LaTeX run, but when your list is final, you can remove it.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.nmc}
\myvalue{0.35},\anothervalue{42}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numerica}

\nmcReuse

\begin{document}

\nmcEvaluate{\[\sin\alpha\]}[\alpha=\myvalue]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion the package should provide a way to define constants without the need of an external file.

---

#### Proposal for a simpler way, that can coexist with the already existing external file feature

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.nmc}
\comma{22}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numerica}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\nmcConstants}{m}
 {
  \__nmc_reuse_command:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nmc_reuse_command:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {,} { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \__nmc_reuse_defcmds:Nnn ##1 { _props } }
  \bool_set_true:N \l__nmc_reuse_retrieved_bool
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\nmcReuse
\nmcConstants{\myvalue{0.35},\anothervalue{42}}

\begin{document}

\nmcEvaluate{\[\sin\alpha\]}[\alpha=\myvalue]

\[\mathit{UltimateComma}=\nmcEvaluate*{\anothervalue+\comma}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I spoke to the author of numerica earlier today and he hopes to post an update to CTAN later this month to address these issues.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I emulated egreg's answer but without expl3, without using the external file, and without numerica's internals. I define a command `\nmccsedef` which acts like `\csedef` but the macro can be used in the `\eval`/`\nmcEvaluate` vv-list:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numerica}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.nmc}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
        
    \def\nmcsingleeval#1{\eval*{x}[x=#1]}
    \def\nmcsingleevalbox#1{\sbox0{\nmcsingleeval{#1}}}
    \def\nmcsingleevalexp#1{\expandafter\nmcsingleevalbox\expandafter{#1}}
    \def\nmccsedef#1#2{\edef\nmccsdeftmp{#2}\nmcsingleevalexp\nmccsdeftmp\nmcReuse[#1]}
    
    My de\nmccsedef{ciappi}{0.35}ar friends (\ciappi):
    \eval{\[\sin\alpha\]}[\alpha=\ciappi]

    \nmccsedef{ciappini}{\fpeval{0.15+0.20}}
    \eval{\[\sin\alpha\]}[\alpha=\ciappini]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: latex output]